# Search through child records fields of given parent using hibernate lucene search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, full-text-search, hibernate-search

I have two tables for example Books, Author. Every book reord is referenced by author id.
I would like to search books which matches given keyword but specific to given author.
How to achieve this using hibernate lucene search?
Do I need to use filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the Hibernate Search documentation: you have an example with exactly that in the first section of the documentation.

Start at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#_configuration . You'll have every steps explained in the following paragraphs.

You can use the Hibernate Search DSL to build your query easily by first matching your keyword on the book fields, then matching the author using the author.id field.

Comment: matching() method is not matching whole content. It's matching part of content. For example, matching("e7e36af9") method matches both e7e36af9-1379-4ebf-92c1-a56daf5e1494 and e7e36af9-8995-4109-ae99-6cbc6d8c027d but i want records with the exact value.

Comment: You need to use a keyword based analyzer (see KeywordTokenizer) instead of the StandardAnalyzer. See the analyzer section of the documentation. Anyway, this is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for KeywordTokenizer is @Field(analyze = Analyze.NO). It also matches exact value.